# ¿Como mostrar un resultado en DataGriedView?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

**Hola sigo en el tema del DataGriedView está vez me gustaría saber cómo puedo mostrar mi resultado en una columna de un DataGriedView de momento sólo he podido hacerlo en etiquetas y textbox pero yo lo necesito en su respectiva celda tengo este código saludos **

```
private void btnCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double total = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            double a = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[0].Value);
            double b = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[1].Value);
            row.Cells[2].Value = a - b;
            total += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].Value);
        }
        label1.Text = total.ToString();
    }
```

**De antemano gracias

Imagen de muestra[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]**

Answer (score 1):

Para ahorrarte líneas de código podes hacer la suma con linq.

```
double resul = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.Cells["NombreColumna"].Value));
```

Para mostrar el resultado en la misma columna arias.

```
DataGridViewRow rowtotal = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
    rowtotal.Cells["NombreColumna"].Value = resul;
```

En mi blog tengo un articulo que explica un ejemplo solo que usando datatable. 
[Sumar Datagridview con Linq](http://cristiantorresalfaro.blogspot.com/2012/08/sumar-columnas-datagridview-usando-linq.html?m=1)